# How can I fetch an email page and submit form data to it?

Tags: php, javascript, autofill

I was trying to automate login to my emails through my own website. Here is what I have managed till now. I don't want to save my data on my computer because it is a shared one.

```
<?php

$src=file_get_contents('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=http://mail.google.com/mail/&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2');

?>

<html>
<body>
<?php echo $src; ?>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
 document.getElementsByName('Email').item(0).value='testusername@gmail.com';
 document.getElementsByName('Passwd').item(0).value='testpassword';
 document.getElementsByName('signIn').item(0).click();
 void(0);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Why does this not work? Any ideas? I'm new to web programming, so any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you're trying to play with a very paranoid log-in web page. I don't think is even possible to do what you're trying and if it is is no gonna be as simple as this. Also if you're able to achieve it the result is not gonna work for long because any change in the page or in its security check steps are gonna make your trick to fail again, and I'm sure this page is in a very active development.

Comment: Even if it was possible, you'd be putting your username and password on the source (risk), and making your email accessible to anyone who opens the page (risk).

Comment: If you really want to play with your Gmail account you can do it in its own terms: using standard POP/IMAP/SMTP protocols.

Comment: If auto login is your problem, what's wrong with the built-in browser auto-fill? or better yet, what's wrong typing your username and password in Gmail manually anyway?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Google deny executing of authorisation requests using scripts. There are some ways to prevent this behaviour. I'm sure Google does all necessary things for it.

I can suggest you to use Lastpass browser extension to autologin. In has the master password that you must to remember. It's secure enough even for computers with public access. Until someone get your master password, he doesn't have access to all your saved passwords.

But nothing can protect you from keyboard loggers and network sniffers. So it's totally hopeless.

Comment: Yes, I understand that there would be certain scripts that would prevent such actions, but the same script runs when I run it manually (I made a bookmark with the same JavaScript code) and it works fine when I use it on the Gmail login page.

Comment: As an afterthought, is there a way to fetch the html code of the page and then make certain modifications in it automatically, so that my onload() function replaces the onload() function of the page?

Comment: Also, what about using methods like
1. cURL
2. OpenAuth

because I don't know anything about any of these methods, and I don't know how to proceed either. Any guidance? please :)

Comment: There is big difference between executing of code in browser and execuing of code on third-party server. Google trusts your browser, it behaves like normal browser (saves cookies, executing redirects etc), a bookmarklet just simulates normal user activity. But when you do something using simple HTTP libraries (file_get_contents, curl etc), Google can recognize that because this library doesn't behave like normal user.

Comment: You can't modify page and insert some code into it because google use HTTPS, it disallows this behaviour. You can setup your own proxy server, break HTTPS and modify page, but it will be less secure because HTTPS is really good and prevents network sniffing. And I think google can prevent this behaviour too. OpenAuth isn't helpful in this case. You're just trying to solve the problem the wrong way. There are solutions that help you to setup your secure private environment on public computer. You should try one of them.